# CRT Debug Heap reports leak when including exception_ptr.hpp

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, boost-thread

I created a Win32 Console application with Visual Studio 2013 (vc12) and Boost 1.56.0.

This is my only file:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

//#define CHECK_THREAD

#ifdef CHECK_THREAD

#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#else

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define DEBUG_CLIENTBLOCK   new( _CLIENT_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#else
#define DEBUG_CLIENTBLOCK
#endif // _DEBUG

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_CLIENTBLOCK
#endif

#include <boost/exception/detail/exception_ptr.hpp>

#endif

#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hLogFile = CreateFile(L"MemoryLeaks.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    //Turn on debugging for memory leaks. This is automatically turned off when the build is Release.
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, hLogFile);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ERROR, hLogFile);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ASSERT, hLogFile);

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

    CloseHandle(hLogFile);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this (Win32/Debug on Windows 7) I get the following output in MemoryLeaks.txt:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
c:\workspace\externals\boost_1_56_0\include\boost\smart_ptr\detail\shared_count.hpp(130) : {156} client block at 0x00709AC8, subtype 0, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <            0 p > 84 0F 0C 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 30 9A 70 00 
{155} normal block at 0x00709A88, 14 bytes long.
 Data: <bad exception > 62 61 64 20 65 78 63 65 70 74 69 6F 6E 00 
c:\workspace\externals\boost_1_56_0\include\boost\exception\detail\exception_ptr.hpp(130) : {154} client block at 0x00709A30, subtype 0, 44 bytes long.
 Data: <        @       > 04 0E 0C 00 00 00 00 00 40 0E 0C 00 F0 0C 0C 00 
c:\workspace\externals\boost_1_56_0\include\boost\smart_ptr\detail\shared_count.hpp(130) : {151} client block at 0x007089B0, subtype 0, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <h           X p > 68 0F 0C 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 58 89 70 00 
c:\workspace\externals\boost_1_56_0\include\boost\exception\detail\exception_ptr.hpp(130) : {150} client block at 0x00708958, subtype 0, 44 bytes long.
 Data: <        X       > B4 0C 0C 00 00 00 00 00 58 0D 0C 00 F0 0C 0C 00 
Object dump complete.
```

I first discovered this issue in a unit test which included boost/thread.hpp. However the unit tests don't include source and line information about the leak and thread.hpp doesn't compile with the DEBUG_CLIENTBLOCK macro. So I started eliminating all includes until I found out that the one causing the reported leak was exception_ptr and luckily enough this one did compile with the macro.

I opened a ticket to Boost about it (https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10621) but I thought I'd try here as well. I guess it's also possible I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: +1 for the effort. I expect this to be expected behaviour on because the heap report is triggered inside `main()`. Would be nice to have a MSVC buff chime in though.

Comment: Please don't `#include <Windows.h>` Windows.h without `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` and `#define NOMINMAX`.

Comment: @sehe Like I said, my original problem is with a unit test I have. I am now upgrading my project to latest protobuf and latest boost with VC12 instead of VC10 and after all these upgrades the unit tests still pass, but Boost reports the leak. With quite a lot of elimination I managed to find the root cause. Before all the upgrades there was no leak reported. (and thanks for the +1 :-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the question, this is a bug in Boost.
You can see the ticket I opened here: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10621

In the meantime, since we moved to VC12, we started using std::thread, so in my sepcific case, it's not a problem any more.

Comment: fwiw, you can setup the debugger to break on a specific allocation number by assigning `_crtBreakAlloc = 156`.

Comment: yes, I know that, but it's definitely a problem with Boost, since there's no code of my own there.